# Hadoop/Pig CSVExcelStorage with different delimiter

Tags: csv, hadoop, apache-pig

Using the following input file with PiggyBank's CSVExcelStorage works just fine:

```
Col1,Col2,Col3
1,2,3
"1","2","3"
```

The small pig script

```
REGISTER /usr/lib/pig/piggybank.jar;
DEFINE CSVExcelStorage org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.CSVExcelStorage; 
a = LOAD '/path/to/file.csv' USING CSVExcelStorage()
b = FOREACH a GENERATE $1;
DUMP b
```

works as expected and returns

```
(Col2)
(2)
(2)
```

Doing the same thing with a semi colon as separator does not work:

```
Col1;Col2;Col3
1;2;3
"1";"2";"3"
```

The adjusted pig script

```
REGISTER /usr/lib/pig/piggybank.jar;
DEFINE CSVExcelStorage org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.CSVExcelStorage; 
a = LOAD '/path/to/file.csv' USING CSVExcelStorage(';')
b = FOREACH a GENERATE $1;
DUMP b
```

simply returns

```
()
()
()
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Typo: `b = FOREACH b GENERATE $1;` should be `b = FOREACH a GENERATE $1;`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found a solution myself. The `DEFINE` statement is the issue and prevents the argument from being passed to `CSVExcelStorage()`. The following will work as expected:

```
REGISTER /usr/lib/pig/piggybank.jar;
a = LOAD '/path/to/file.csv' USING org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.CSVExcelStorage(';')
b = FOREACH a GENERATE $1;
DUMP b
```

Comment: Actually, the `DEFINE` statement did not cause the issue. Rather, you could have written the `DEFINE` statement like so: `DEFINE CSVExcelStorage org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.CSVExcelStorage(';');`. This would have allowed your first attempt to work.